# Magento 1.9 - Only Date Day Format in Email Template

Tags: email, magento, templates, variables, format

The following e-mail variable outputs this format by default: "dd/mm/yyyy hh mm ss"

```
{{var order.getCreatedAtFormated()}}
```

What i need is just the day "dd" for recurring orders. Is this even possible?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Try below things if it might be work for you.

```
{{var order.getCreatedAtFormatedHideTime('short')}}
```

Comment: Hi, thx for your response. Unfortunately the variable returns nothing. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In Order Model, add new function to return format date you want.
Order Model locate at app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php

Add new function with your own format:

```
public function getCreatedAtEmail()
    {
        return date("Y-m-d",strtotime($this->getCreatedAtStoreDate()));
    }
```

In your email html, you can call it by {{var order.getCreatedAtEmail()}}